# Foreman install not working under vanilla install

Tags: foreman

I'm new to foreman and am having trouble gettin this working on a rhel (6.5) server. Here's the error I get when running "foreman-installer -v":

```
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:42 verbose] Running validation checks
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:42 verbose] Executing hooks in group pre
[ WARN 2014-08-04 15:25:42 verbose] Hook 'Kafo::HookContext' is using block with arguments which is DEPRECATED, access to kafo instance is provided by hook DSL, please remove |kafo| from your hook block
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:42 verbose] All hooks in group pre finished
[ WARN 2014-08-04 15:25:43 verbose]  Sections other than main, master, agent, user are deprecated in puppet.conf. Please use the directory environments feature to specify environments. (See http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/environments.html)
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:43 verbose]    (at /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/settings/config_file.rb:77:in `collect'; /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/settings/config_file.rb:77:in `unique_sections_in'; /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/settings/config_file.rb:23:in `parse_file'; /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/settings.rb:535:in `parse_config'; /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/settings.rb:597:in `parse_config_files'; /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/settings.rb:247:in `initialize_global_settings'; /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet.rb:150:in `do_initialize_settings_for_run_mode'; /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet.rb:136:in `initialize_settings'; /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:86:in `execute'; /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util.rb:479:in `exit_on_fail'; /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:85:in `execute'; /usr/bin/puppet:8)
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:44 verbose]  Loading facts in /usr/share/foreman-installer/modules/concat/lib/facter/concat_basedir.rb
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:44 verbose]  Loading facts in /usr/share/foreman-installer/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:44 verbose]  Loading facts in /usr/share/foreman-installer/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:44 verbose]  Loading facts in /usr/share/foreman-installer/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:44 verbose]  Loading facts in /usr/share/foreman-installer/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/root_home.rb
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:44 verbose]  Loading facts in /usr/share/foreman-installer/modules/firewall/lib/facter/iptables_version.rb
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:44 verbose]  Loading facts in /usr/share/foreman-installer/modules/firewall/lib/facter/ip6tables_version.rb
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:44 verbose]  Loading facts in /usr/share/foreman-installer/modules/firewall/lib/facter/iptables_persistent_version.rb
[ WARN 2014-08-04 15:25:45 verbose]  Config file /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml not found, using Hiera defaults
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:53 verbose] /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb:287: [BUG] Segmentation fault
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:53 verbose] ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:53 verbose]
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:53 verbose] sh: line 1:  9739 Done                    echo '$kafo_config_file="/etc/foreman/foreman-installer.yaml"   include kafo_configure'
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:53 verbose]       9740 Aborted                 |    RUBYLIB=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kafo-0.5.4/lib/kafo/../..//modules: puppet apply --verbose --debug --trace --color=false --show_diff --detailed-exitcodes --modulepath /usr/share/foreman-installer/modules:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kafo-0.5.4/modules
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:53 verbose] Puppet has finished, bye!
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:53 verbose] Executing hooks in group post
[ INFO 2014-08-04 15:25:53 verbose] All hooks in group post finished
    Something went wrong! Check the log for ERROR-level output
    The full log is at /var/log/foreman-installer/foreman-installer.log
```

Can someone please help me identify where things are going wrong?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Is the system up to date?

Comment: Largely it is, but I can verify anything in particular you have in mind?

Comment: Well, it's obvious that Ruby is crashing, so you should verify that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solved*

Hopefully this will help others:

The error messages didn't state what was the issue. Perserverance and troubelshooting highlighted the need for the following packages:

ruby193-rubygem-foreman_setup
ruby193-rubygem-foreman_bootdisk
genisoimage
ipxe-bootimgs

Foreman 1.5 is now up and running.

Thanks all for your help.

Dan

Comment: Dan, I am having the same problem. How did you install those packages?